# How compare charts using a List<T> with LiveCharts?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm trying to compare a lot of charts using [Live Charts](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Line%20Chart) according with the numbers of classes inside my List.

I'm trying some like this:

```
    class MyClass 
    {
        IList<double> a;
        IList<double> b;
    }
```

And to make a chart:

```
    List<MyClass> aLotOfCharts = new List<MyClass>

    for(int i=0; i < aLotOfCharts.Count; i++)
    {                    
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double> (aLotOfCharts[i].a)
            },
         };
    }
```

I expect three charts with the "a" Data, but the actual output is only the last position of "aLotOfCharts.a".

I know I need to create more "new LineSeries" to input more charts, but I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: I think your question is very simple, and you say it at the end. We need to read all your explanation to finally find your question is simplest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the Live Chart, but I think the answer is something like this:

```cs
List<MyClass> aLotOfCharts = new List<MyClass>()
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection()

for(int i=0; i < aLotOfCharts.Count; i++)
{
    SeriesCollection.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double> (aLotOfCharts[i].a)
            });
}
```